# Closure in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
function returnVerse(x){
   return function(x) {console.log(x);};
}

for(var x = 9; x>=0; x--){
   return returnVerse(x)();
}
```

I just get undefined as a result.

I've been inspiring myself from this:
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

I understand that this is a scope issue, so I'm trying to create a closure, what am I not getting here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the context you show, you can't return inside a for-loop

Comment: `returnVerse(x)(x);` your second function requires, but is not sent a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last function you're returning is the last one you're calling, and it's called with just `()`, meaning no arguments, yet you've specified an argument in the inner function, and it's `undefined`.

```
function returnVerse(x){
                 //  ^ outer argument

   return function(x) { 
                // ^ inner argument overwrites outer argument

       console.log(x); // undefined
   };

}

for(var x = 9; x>=0; x--){
   return returnVerse(x)();
                //    ↑  ^ innner argument not passed, "undefined"
                      outer argument   
}
```

Just don't specify an argument in the inner function, and the argument from the outer function will be in scope, and enclosed (closure)

```
function returnVerse(x){
   return function() {console.log(x);};
}

for(var x=9; x>=0; x--){
   returnVerse(x)();
}
```

Also, returning from the `for` loop makes little sense, and means it only runs once